# Can't set clock using SetSystemTime on Windows 8

Tags: c, winapi, windows-8

My app uses `SetSystemTime()` to set the PC clock from a GPS source.  This works fine in Windows 7 with User Account Control disabled, but in Windows 8, even with UAC disabled, it fails.  The error I get back is `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`.  The user logged into the machine is in the Administrators group.  I can only get it to work if I run the application as "Run as Administrator" from the file's context menu in Explorer - but the logged-in user IS an Administrator.

So... what do I need to do differently on Windows 8 to get `SetSysytemTime()` to work?  Do I need even more elevated privileges than the current users' Administrator rights?  If so, what has higher privileges than Administrator?  Or do I need to set the user account up differently to allow these kinds of calls to work on Windows 8?

EDIT: As noted in the comments, manually attempting to enable the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege doesn't work.  Neither does trying to add the privilege using the suggested MSDN method of `LsaAddAccountRights`.

Comment: The "UAC disabled" angle is a very murky one, it can't be disabled afaik.  Almost definitely not on Win8, the underlying plumbing is used to provide the sandbox in which Metro apps run.  You'll need a manifest to ask for elevation or start your app from a process that is already elevated.

Comment: It gives the option to turn UAC off still... so is it sort of not actually disabled then?  How annoying!

Comment: "The calling process must have the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege. This privilege is disabled by default. The SetSystemTime function enables the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege before changing the system time and disables the privilege before returning. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges."  -- maybe in Windows 8, the privilege isn't automatically enabled any more and you have to do it yourself with AdjustTokenPrivileges()? Could be worth trying.

Comment: Ok, I've tried adjusting the token priviledge - it still fails.  It claims not to hold that priviledge, so it can't enable it.  Guess I'll just have to enable the priviledge from Security Policy, or add it to the user's account prililedge using `LsaAddAccountRights`?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be related to the fact that, with UAC disabled on Windows 8, processes (by default) run at Medium Integrity, not High Integrity (see [this post](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/140/)).

I think you need to request `requireAdministrator` in your [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Damien, that would make sense.  How annoying though.  I understand why Microsoft want (/need) to do this, it just break our application's need to sync the system clock with our server service, as the client app has to be able to run without user interaction in a lot of systems (some users won't have the Administrative login to elevate the process, but the app still needs that level of permission to do low-level things).  Will have to think of a workaround I guess, as prompting for elevated permissions isn't practical.

Comment: @NickShaw - well, it *is* a privileged operation. If the users won't have permission to perform the operation, maybe it's time to re-write (part of?) this program as a service?

Comment: The odd thing is that my logged in user can change the clock without any prompts, yet my app running under the same user can't unless I specifically run it "as Administrator".

I agree though; having a service do these privileged operations is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Just to confirm: Setting `requireAdministrator` in the manifest does indeed work.

Answer (score 4):

If you move the UAC slider down completely in "User Account Control Settings", it means that UAC won't show any prompts, but is still enabled. Any normal process still runs without administrative privileges, but elevating (by "run as administrator" or by having declared "requireAdministrator") will happen without user consent.

Disabling the Security Policy "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" or setting the registry key "EnableLUA" to 0 will change this behaviour, but prevent *all* <s>Metro</s> Modern UI apps from running.

If your users don't have administrative rights, you can't change the system clock without using a service.

If you want your application to start normally (but without special rights) for normal users *and* (auto-)elevate for administrators, you may want to declare "highestAvailable" in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks Felix, useful to know.  Looks like I'll be writing a service to do the job then! :)