# c# - How to run Commdan Prompt in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, command-prompt

I have a windows service, written in c# and I need to run cmd in this service to get remote server's system time.

This is my code to obtain system time from remote server:

```
    public static void GetNetworkTime()
    {
        //To disable automatic update from time server
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\W32Time\\Parameters", true);
        key.SetValue("Type", "NoSync");
        key.Close();

        //Run cmd.exe with "net time \\\\192.168.2.147 /set /yes" command
        Process proc = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/c net time \\\\192.168.2.147 /set /yes";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        //Get client time
        DateTime clientDate = DateTime.Now;
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        //Get server time from updated time of client
        DateTime serverDate = DateTime.Now;

        //Write info to log file
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        try
        {
            sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\LogFile.txt", true);
            sw.WriteLine("Client time is: " + clientDate);
            sw.WriteLine("Server time is: " + serverDate);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Also, this is my service code. It supposes to check server time in every 30 seconds and update client time. Service is working but it is not updating time of my computer according to server time.

```
namespace NetTimeService
{
  public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
  {
    private Timer timer1 = null;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 30000;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Test windows service started");

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Library.GetNetworkTime();
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Client time has been set");
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Timer ticked!");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Test windows service stopped");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the account the service is running under doesn't have the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege. Possible duplicate of [Can't set clock using SetSystemTime on Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076140/cant-set-clock-using-setsystemtime-on-windows-8)

Comment: Why not just setup the built in windows date/time ntp service so you just set it once and not run a service of your own

Comment: Actually, I tried to use ntp service but I couldn't make it work. Also, I am planning to use this service to write updated clients' time to database. This is why I don't want to use built in ntp service Is there a way to get info about when system clock is updated from ntp service? If it is yes, It can be useful for me.