# How to set the PC system time in Windows using VS C++ 2013

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to set over time my PC time in Windows in C++. It doesn't work. 
I already run my project as administrator.
I asked some privileges to effcetion this task.
But nothing, etc...

Could you have some ideas about it ?

Here is my code :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
  SYSTEMTIME st;
  ZeroMemory(&st, sizeof(st));
  HANDLE hToken;
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

  // Enable the required privilege
  OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken);
  LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);
  tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1; // valider deux privileges , tkp contient les parametres de chaque privilege
  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; // je valide le privilege 1
  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0); // pour valider ou desactiver les privileges dans un acces precis.
                                                                             // LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[1].Luid);
                                                                             // tkp.Privileges[1].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; // je valide le privilege 2

                                                                             // Set system time
  st.wHour = 15;
  st.wMinute = 15;
  SetSystemTime(&st);

  GetSystemTime(&st);
  printf("The system time is: %02d:%02d\n", st.wHour, st.wMinute);

  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Re: `void main()` is invalid in C++. The return type of main must be `int`.

Comment: Most of the WINAPI functions you use can fail, but you didn't do _any_ error checking. Add error checking and see what happens

Comment: really `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege have only elevated processes in token and you not need try yourself enable it in token - the `SetSystemTime` do this yourself. faster of all you not run elevated

Comment: Thank you Michael.  All WINAPI functions work only   SetSystemTime(&st) that fails. I don't know why?

Comment: There are two problems: 1. `SetSystemTime(&st);` fails because the values in `st` are incorrect.. Put the `SystemTime(&st);` _after_ `GetSystemTime`. 2. With that correction it still fails, but not for the same reaseon: Read this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27b2b2ba-7226-4ac3-99b7-ce689748fff5/windows-10-setsystemtime-fails-with-errorprivilegenotheld-1314?forum=windowssecurity

Comment: BTW: if `SetSystemTime` fails you can get the error number using `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @GeraudWATI your code (with suggested corrections) works if your process is elevated. The acceped answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076140/cant-set-clock-using-setsystemtime-on-windows-8) resolves your problem.

Comment: You want to set the time on your machine? Well, the correct solution to that problem is to let an existing [NTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) client (that you *should* already be running) do it for you.

Comment: Thank you very . It works well.... I run  as administrator

Comment: the posted code contains both 'C' and 'C++' actions.  suggest picking one or the other..  For instance,  `#include <stdio.h>` is a C header file.  Suggest: `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: I would think you could call `system( "time ...." );` to set the RTC clock